# Write a permutation as a product of transpositions.

Tags: permutations

> Let $\alpha = (1 \ 6 \ 3) (2 \ 9) (4 \ 8 \ 10) \in S_{10}$ be a permutation. Write $\alpha$ as a product of transpositions, i.e. of cyclic permutations of order 2. Note that transpositions do not need to be disjunked.

Really don't know how to "go/walk" on this.

I think that $$1->6, 6->3$$

$$2->9$$ $$5->8, 7->10$$ 
So something like $$(1 6)(6 3)(3 2)(2 9)(9 4)(4 8)(8 10)$$

Comment: Can you write $(163)$ as a product of transpositions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $(a_1a_2\dots a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_2a_3)\dots(a_{n-1}a_n)$.

Comment: α=(1 6 3)(2 9)(4 8 10) with your hint we got; $\alpha_1$=1, $\alpha_2$=6, $\alpha_3$=3, $\alpha_4$=2, $\alpha_5$=9, $\alpha_6$=4, $\alpha_7$=8, $\alpha_8$=10, or?

Comment: Well, just split $(163)=(16)(63)$.  I leave $(4 8 10)$ for you.

Comment: ahh (1 6)(6 3)(2 9)(4 8)(8 10)